# Can't get map tag to work correctly

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I'm having a really hard time getting the mapping tag to work correctly for an image. Wondering if someone can take a look and see what I'm doing wrong.
The problem i'm having is getting the map to even appear. Images all load fine but when I map and link a certain part (or the entire image) nothing appears.

HTML:

```
<div id="leftColumn">
<img src="/img1.jpg"><br><br>
<img src="/img2.jpg"><br><br>
<img src="/img3.jpg" usemap="#Map2" border="0">
<map name="Map2">
<area shape="rect" coords="80,298,371,377" href="www.SomeSite.com">
</map><br><br>
</div>
```

CSS if it matters:

```
#leftColumn {
    height: 100%;
    width: 61%;
    float: left;
}
```

I think this is correct but maybe something from dreamweaver to the actual site isn't properly doing the coords? I have no idea but I've been stuck at this..

Comment: What's the problem? Does the area render in the wrong place? does clicking that area navigate to the wrong place?

Comment: And what is the problem? I could see several: images are not shown, map is not on the images...

Comment: Sorry i'll edit to specify but I don't know if it's even rendering in the right place. Basically, nothing shows up. I can map the entire image and there still isn't any link showing up on it.

Comment: What is the location of the file with html code and what is the location of the img3.jpg image file on the harddrive?

Comment: Uh I believe the HTML code is on a server, I only have access to the body portion of it so when I write to it, it's just saved. The img files are being pulled via filezilla.

Comment: The code shown in the question works properly (provided the image is large enough to include the area you've defined.)  You do need to add a protocol (`http://` or `https://`) to the href, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be several issues:

- the image file is linked as it is in the root of the webserver, try ./img3.jpg
- make sure dimensions of the mapped image is more than the map coordinates, ie in this case 298x377 px
- you set the div#leftColumn to be width: 61%; of what?, does the image fit to that width?

EDIT

- The image is 1530 x 380 pixels (fixed dimensions)
- Your map has 291 x 79 pixels (fixed dimension)
- The image is in dynamically resized element to 61 % of width of parent element

Solution:
  - keep fixed size of the image / parent element..
  - enlarge the map dimensions

Comment: I do have to change the image file on dreamweaver to see it and map it correctly, then I change that file back to the server to pull it from(could this be an issue?)
The width is set to 61% because there's a right side div with a width of 39%.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image with the map?

Comment: It's at 1530 x 380. However I know it's definitely not that huge when I see it on the website. More like 720 x 180. (idk why your getting downvoted for helping me either..)

Comment: I figured it out.. after you mentioned the dimensions of the image and mapped dimensions. I told it to have a fixed size WxH and once i did that, the mapping translated over correctly.

Comment: Very good ;) Just accept the answer to get this question closed. BTW, meanwhile I edited my original answer with some exact numbers ;)

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help!